# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor.configure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am getting below exception in server start when using async completableFuture in spring boot.

I am new to spring boot multiThreading. Any other jars need to add for this functionality.

Below mentioned spring frameworks jars are used.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Code:- I have configured task executor thread pool in the config file for this async method

```java
    @Service
    public class fileGeneration {
    @Async
        public CompletableFuture<String[]> generatefile(){
            ...
    
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(fileGenerationResponse);
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace: In server start this exception occurred.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor.configure(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)V
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:51,944 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.buildAdvice(AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.java:154)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:51,975 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.<init>(AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.java:107)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:51,990 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,006 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,053 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1732)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,069 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,100 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,115 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,131 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,194 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,209 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,272 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,334 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,350 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,365 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,428 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,428 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,444 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,459 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,522 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,537 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,553 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,584 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,615 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,631 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,694 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
         
        2020-06-26 21:02:52,709 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
```

Comment: Can you post your class which you're trying to enable async?

Comment: @HưngChu updated my code

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? It seems a mismatch of version dependency.

Comment: @WoAiNii i updated my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml needed is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>async-method</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>async-method</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Asynchronous is from spring-boot-starter-web dependency.
you can refer https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: Yeah, I already have spring-boot-starter-web dependency right but still issue exists

Comment: do check with the above link, you might have missed some annotatiions

Answer (score 0):

Mark your service with @EnableAsync annotation. Seems like it missing this one

Comment: The Service class (which has `@Async` method defined) need not be annotated with `@EnableAsync`. instead, you need to have another separate class where you are initializing ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.  the class needs to be annotated with `@Configuration &  @EnableAsync`.